# Cannot get Jquery .ajax or .load to execute scripts

Tags: jquery

Here's test.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language=javascript>

$(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click( function() {
            $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:101/test2.html",
            dataType : "html",
            success: function(data){  alert(data);  $("div").html(data);  }
            });
            });
});
/*
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:101/Scripts/testscript.js",
            dataType : "script"
            //success: function(data){    $("#inner-main").html(data);  }
            });
});
*/
</script>
<button> bleh </button>
<div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's test2.html :

```
<script type=javascript>
alert("lock and load, outside!");
                                    $(document).ready(function () {
                                        alert("lock and load!");
                                    });    

</script>
<p>Hello, world </p>
```

I cannot get test1 to load test2 and execute scripts in it.
I do get < p > (Hello World) to display in the div. The scripts though, do not execute.
The only alert I see is from the function called on success.

What am I doing wrong ?

The URL to test1.html is http://localhost:101/test1.html

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: No, not in IE9 (F12 developer tools, script tab)

Comment: I've tried running this is IE9, Opera 11, Chrome. Doesn't work in any of them.

Comment: why dont you use `jquery load` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your scripts, change

`<script language=javascript>` and `<script type=javascript>`

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

It will work.

Before learning and using AJAX, I recommend you learn valid HTML first. This is not valid HTML so why would jQuery or even browser will compile it correctly?

Comment: This is correct info, but it should work even with this broken

Comment: No, it _should_ not. Of course, it may but if it is then it's just a matter of chance.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:
Try this url in your ajax call:

```
url : "test2.html",
```

Hope this helps. Cheers